# Solving for r in the equation $\int_{0}^{13} \frac{230}{(t+1)^{r} } dt = 375$

Tags: calculus

How can I solve for r in the equation  $\int_{0}^{13}  \frac{230}{  \big(t+1\big)^{r}  } dt = 375$

Comment: Can you compute the integral  if you assume $r$ given?

Comment: Yes, the previous questions in the problem give r as 2 and 3 respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\int\frac1{(t+1)^r}\,dt=\begin{cases}-\frac1{r-1}(t+1)^{-(r-1)} & r\ne-1\\\ln(t+1) & r=-1\end{cases}$$

Unfortunately, the solution $r$ is not very nice. [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=375%3Dintegral+of+230%2F%28t%2B1%29%5Er+from+t%3D0+to+t%3D13) gives a messy answer in terms of the Lambert W-function. The best you're probably going to do is an approximation $(\approx 1.39979)$, or an implicit form: the unique solution to $$\frac{230}{r-1}\left(1-\frac1{14^{r-1}}\right)=375.$$

Comment: I see, I assumed since the area = 375 that r certainly does not = -1, and therefore did not consider ln(t+1). However I am having trouble solving for this using logarithms. Any help on that end would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not a surprise that you're having trouble. See the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I assumed that there was not a straight forward solution to this problem.